# IntelliJ 14 Find Usages/Refactoring with JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, intellij-idea

So I have some questions and wondering whether they are not possible in intelliJ or whether im just doing it wrong ;)

I have a spring boot thymeleaf project, working in frontend I have some problems with finding usages, refactoring and jumping to js, and css files.

More specifically:

- Sometimes when I click on a .js or .css file and use find usages
  (project files) i might not find anything, sometimes I do
- Refactoring
  may or may not find usages as well which means I can’t rely on it
- Sometimes I can ctrl click a link to a css or js file when it is in a
  webjar but not otherwise.

I have set my javascript library folder/s in Intellij under settings/preferences, I have also invalidated caches/restarted a few times.
I have all my files under webapp in sub directories (should I mark them as resources under project structure?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with refactoring of image files, css files, is that are not resolved. Means that you can't navigate to image by ctrl+clicking the image name in src="./images/SC_logo.svg" ?

then it looks like you need to mark the folder that contains img subfolder as Resource Root at File | Settings | Directories.

URL paths will be resolved against "resource roots" where applicable. For instance, in HTML  or  elements, relative URLs are looked up against resource roots.

You should start typing within the href or src attributes, then auto-completion will suggest items in those directories, and URLs which cannot be resolved will helpfully be marked as a warning.

When the URL is resolved that Refactoring will work.